# In Continuum (TV show), why doesn't Keira use invisibility more often?

Tags: technology, continuum

She's in a fight and DOESN'T become invisible????  Why the heck not?  Sure, when Carlos is around she might not want to use it -- not least because she doesn't want her own partner to shoot her by accident -- but when he's not around, why not?

Does activating invisibility lower the suit's protection level?

[Minor spoiler below]

> I realize she's without the suit for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Out of universe we want to see the hot girl kicking ass and the writers know it.

In universe the invisibility field has to use a significant amount of power so if she does not believe she needs the tactical advantage it offers in a particular fight she will not use it and save it for a time it is needed.